# Application View is Shrinked on Android 4.2 and Below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am building a HTML5 based mobile application using JS, jQuery 1.11.2, jQuery-mobile 1.4.5 and custom CSS. The application is build using cordova framework. The app functions on all the Andrdoid devices (which I could gather) having different Android versions. While the functionality is working, the pages (text, button-size, navigation bars, etc) appear shrinked in mobile devices with Android 4.2 or below. For higher android versions (4.4, 5.0) the application looks and works perfectly fine.
I have included the below meta-tag hoping to solve the issue but it has not:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

I am not posting the code on purpose as:

1. It is a big piece of code
2. I do not know what exactly will help you identify the issue
   If there is any specific portion of code to be pasted then please let me know I will update it here.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Abdel Raoof for editing the Q :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below meta tag helped solve the issue:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=auto, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
```